# combine two call commands inside a batch file

Tags: batch-processing

ok, I am writing a BATCH file to change the color of the Text and or background.  Here is what I have so far:

```
@echo off

:: Sets the size of the command window

mode con: cols=62 lines=40

:: Sets the TITLE of the command window

::ACTUAL PROGRAM STARTS HERE

title=Text Color Chart for BATCH

SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1)
do rem"') do (

  set "DEL=%%a"
)

call :ColorText 0a "  0a prints in Green"

call :ColorText 0b "  0b prints in Auqa"

call :ColorText 0c "  0c prints in Red"

call :ColorText 0d "  0d prints in Purple"

call :ColorText 0e "  0e prints in Yellow"

call :ColorText 0f "  0f prints in white"

echo.
pause
goto :eof
:: since :eof does not exist, the program ends here!


:: ============= SUBROUTINES START HERE ======================

:ColorText

echo off

<nul set /p .=. > "%~2"

findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul

echo(%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%

del "%~2" > nul 2>&1

exit /b

:: ============== SUBROUTINES STOP HERE ======================
```

Now my question, is there a way to combine two "CALLS" to echo out on the same line?
**Example:   call :ColorText 01 "Hello" + call :ColorText 0c "World!"**

So the printout would be (in Green)Hello (space) (in Red)World!

Thank you in advance for any help you guys can offer!